# Break after inline-block quirks with doctypes

Tags: html, css, doctype

I updating a website and trying to prepare it for a move from its current doctype to the html 5 one. Currently if I use the css below:

```
br {
  line-height: 5px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and html:

```
<div>div 1</div>
<br>
<div>div 2</div>
```

with doctype:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

It renders so that there is no gap between the two div's, the breaks line-height is applied to the same line as the first div not on it's own line.

If I use the same css and html with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The break is rendered on it's own line giving the 5px break which seems more logical to me for this particular element. Is there a css solution that would render the 5px gap under both doctypes as I transition?

I thought about giving the div bottom padding or a margin but I think that will lead to issues if the div's are nested.

Comment: Do you really need the divs to be `inline-block`s? Do you need them to stretch to the width of their contents? Otherwise, just remove that and take advantage of the div's `block` property to have them in separate lines.

Comment: I simplified the example there are actually a few inline divs before the break.

Comment: The two doctypes should make no difference in rendering, and they didn’t when I tested. The current content may have something that throws some browsers to Quirks Mode, such as a comment before the doctype.
In general, it is unproductive to convert existing sites from one HTML version to another, except as part of major redesign. Especially if a move from Quirks Mode to “standards mode” is involved, there is a huge number of potential, er, quirks hiding around.